# Issue with laravel debugbar in cpanel server

Tags: php, laravel, apache, cpanel, mime-types

I'm using laravel 5.5 and php 7.1 .

In vps, Debugbar is working fine but it is not working in cpanel server.Please have a look bellow attachment for the issue i'm facing.

[image: img1]

Comment: looks as though the css/js of the debugbar is not loading correctly, check the html source and/or browser console/network tab for errors?

Comment: Please have a look at this http://bvcrm.io/public/signin . we are not getting any console errors. Please let us know other solution. Thanks.

Comment: Accessing your URL, it seems you have a `var_dump` / `dd` somewhere in your code that is displaying all that data. Try searching your code for that.

Comment: I think i found the issue, the `Content-Type` header is set [in the code](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/blob/master/src/Controllers/AssetController.php#L40) to the correct mime, but it appears as though cpanel overrides it to `text/html`

Comment: I think you are correct @Quezler, the CSS rules seem to be simply ignored and most likely this is the cause.

Comment: can i get any help to override in the cpanel? it would be more helpful.

Comment: I am not that familiar with cpanel, i googled a little and could find that much on the topic, perhaps there is a rogue .htaccess or webserver configuration overriding the content type?

Comment: You really should not use the debugbar in a production system.

Comment: @apokryfos Yes i know. but i'm getting some errors. I want to find out them. Is there any solution?

Comment: Hello, anybody is there?